# Work done on rectangular loop of wire in uniform magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, work

I have a short question about the following attachments.

[image: Example page 1]
[image]
[image]

**Question:** 
I assume that the increased current $I$ refered to is kept constant, hence we are assuming that $w$ (horizontal component of the speed of the charge) is constant.
Since we have the battery cancelling the horizontal component of the magnetic force, we are left with net force $F_{vert} = IBa$, so the wire accelerates upwards, hence $u$ is not constant. Keeping this in mind is the complete working for the work by the battery then:

$$W_{battery} = \lambda a B w \int u dt  = \lambda a B w \int (\frac{dh}{dt})dt = \lambda a B w h = IBah~?$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your question is unclear. Secondly, if the part you labelled as 'Question' is related to the 'Example 5.3' above, then it is absolutely wrong to suggest an acceleration of the wire upwards, because the weight of the mass hanging is BALANCED by the Lorentz force. So there is zero net acceleration. However on increasing the current further, there will be a net upward acceleration given by $a = \frac{IlB - mg}{m}$.